# Use different slave for same job on different runs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How do we make Jenkins start the Job in a different slave every time it is run. It usually picks the slave which is free, but what if we wish to run the jobs in a different slave environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure your job you should tick the box that says **"Restrict where this project can be run"** and add the name of the specific node you want your job to run on.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? - can you award the answer of that resolved the problem please.

Comment: For this there would be a need to configure the job before I start the build every time. Is there any plugins that will automatically restart the build on a different slave.

Comment: You can use matrix builds for that